# Delete Known Wi-Fi networks

Tags: wi-fi, 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

It seems someone, somewhere has removed the option to view remembered WiFi Networks in 6.0 (Marshmallow). I'm not sure if Android removed this feature, Samsung did, or Sprint did. How do I remove a remembered WiFi network if I'm not in range? This is for a Sprint Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge with Android 6.0.1.

EDIT: Please also note that I do not wish to root my device to remove WiFi networks as I know that is possible.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/141760/how-do-i-forget-an-out-of-range-wi-fi-network-on-a-galaxy-s7

Comment: Why wasn't that marked as a duplicate of mine as this question was 6 hours before that one?

Comment: I guess I can see why it wasn't. I'm asking for a non-root solution.

Comment: Must be a handiwork of Spring or Samsung or both since stock Android M supports removing any saved network. It however allows only when Wi-Fi is enabled regardless of being connected to an SSID. When Wi-Fi is enabled, clicking the [three dots line gives the option "Saved networks"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GLRb1.png). From there I can remove any saved network.