# How do I "forget" an out-of-range Wi-Fi network on a Galaxy S7?

Tags: wi-fi, settings, 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I want to remove old saved networks that are no longer in range. I can forget visible networks, but out-of-range networks are not visible anywhere so I can't do the standard long-tap => "Forget Network" action.

There is no option for "Saved Networks" or "Manage Networks" under the built-in Wi-Fi app's "More" menu.

I have tried a third-party app, [WiFi Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kman.WifiManager&hl=en), where the networks are visible but reported an error on forget:

> Android 6 allows apps to change (edit password, forget) only those networks that were originally "created" in same app.

I quite distinctly remember being able to view saved networks on previous Android phones...

---

My phone *is* rooted, so methods requiring root are acceptable, but it's better if that's not necessary.

---

I have an Australian (CSC XSA) Galaxy S7 Edge (SM-G935F).

---

Apparently this was a problem with the S6, where the 'solution' was to use third-party Wi-Fi management apps that no longer work in Marshmallow.

- http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6-edge/help/how-forget-range-wi-fi-networks-t3137257
- http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s6/596840-how-do-i-forget-saved-wifi-networks-when-they-out-range-samsung-devices.html
- http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s6/567924-how-do-i-remove-saved-wifi-other-locations-my-samsung-galaxy-s6.html
- http://ericscorner.blogspot.com.au/2016/02/how-to-remove-out-of-range-wifi.html

But that no longer works, as per the error message above...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this was (re-)added sometime between the initial release and the Android 7 Nougat update!

From the Wi-Fi menu, go to `Advanced` (top-right corner) and then the `Manage networks` option near the top of the page. You'll get a list of known networks and the ability to edit/delete them, even when out of range.

Answer (score 5):

The method described in this answer does not require root, but it does require that you have a Wi-Fi access point ("router") you control.

---

One possible but very tedious and hacky solution is to host the SSIDs on a Wi-Fi access point you control, so that they are visible on the S7. Then you can "forget" them through the normal Wi-Fi settings page. The list of saved SSIDs can be retrieved (but not altered directly!) with third-party Wi-Fi management apps.

Having an access point capable of hosting "guest" networks/SSIDs is particularly helpful here. Otherwise, you'll need a wired connection so you don't kick yourself out by changing the SSID around.

Of course, this is quite a terrible solution in every way except that it works. So hopefully someone will have a better solution available.

Answer (score 5):

As your device is rooted, you could directly edit the `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` file and remove the networks there. The block for each network looks like this:

```
network={
        ssid="network_ssid"
        psk="secretpassphrase"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        priority=1
}
```

Remove the blocks of the networks you want to get rid off, save the file, reboot – and they should be gone.

For app-based solutions, be welcome to check my list of apps for [Global WiFi Configuration](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_config#group_421). [Super WiFi & Internet Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.superwifi.internetmanager) e.g. claims one of its features being: *Single click to remove wifi network which has not been used since a long time or you wish to remove the one.*

Comment: Hm. That seems to have worked, after a restart. Would be good to have a non-root method though. I'll accept this one later if no-one comes up with one.

Comment: Ok... so... "Super WiFi & Internet Manager" was both utterly broken and full of ads... today I was reminded that fullscreen video ads with audio are a thing, and discovered that an unskippable delay is also a thing. Anyway, back on point: thanks for the suggestions but I guess I'll stick with the root method for now. Open WiFi Cleaner looks like it might work and be helpful for those who use public wifi more than me.

Comment: If *Open Wifi Cleaner* does that job, please let me know – that was the app I had in mind originally, but it didn't seem to fully fit your issue (as it only says to be working for "open APs", forgetting them on disconnect). Wasn't aware of the "ad infection" of the other app – so I'll happily replace it with the FOSS one in my answer! Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: A notice: No reboot is required.

Answer (score 3):

Found the only way to reset the saved network settings after searching for 2 hours on forums.

Go to Settings.
Go to Backup & reset.
Now tap on the “Network settings reset” option.
Hit the “Reset Settings” button.
You will be given another warning, hit the “Reset Settings” button again.

Your welcome!

Comment: Cool, resetting network-specific settings is a good idea. Didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. You're all over complicating it. Go to settings backup and reset and then reset the network and connection part. It'll ask for your pin. Then it clears it all out

Comment: Would that not also clear out networks I *do* want to keep? Though it is another option for those happy to re-add wanted networks.

Answer (score 1):

Settings, Data Usage,Wi-fi, More, Restrict Networks, then select from the list the ones your phone has accumulated which you no longer wish to access.

Comment: This one does let me see networks but there does not seem to be any way to delete them. Long-tapping did nothing. The "restrict" option only prevents background data on that network but does not forget the network.

Answer (score 1):

5 years on -- Android 8 now has a Wifi advanced setting entitled "Manage networks: Manage your saved Wi-Fi networks" ... look ma no root!