# Remove out of range networks on Android 6

Tags: wi-fi

Having issues removing 2 old out of range wifi networks on android 6 - Samsung Galaxy S5 - Corporate phone, therefore Looking for an UNROOTED option.

- Stock settings wont offer the "forget" option
- Resetting all network settings through "backup and reset" has no effect.
- 3rd party apps dont work
- Creating a similar SSID on my router will only create a duplicate...

  Using *Saved networks → select the network* to forget, I was able to delete all but 2 networks that actually have NO "forget" option, just showing security details and "cancel". Seems to be related to the Android 6 platform only allowing the original application that created the network the right to modify or delete networks. [Source](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-network)

Also see this reference for context, which doesn't help since it requires root:

[How do I "forget" an out-of-range Wi-Fi network on a Galaxy S7?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/141760/how-do-i-forget-an-out-of-range-wi-fi-network-on-a-galaxy-s7/155827?noredirect=1#comment199764_155827)

Out of options at this point. Any ideas?

Comment: so how were these two networks added? if they've come from a corporate security policy ("device administrator"), you might not be able to remove them at all

Comment: They don't come from a corporate security policy or administrator. Just normal networks which I connected to at one point or another.